# What would be the best architectural pattern to store user files in Django?

Tags: python, django, architecture, filesystems

I am looking to make a Django-Rest web application that allows users to store files and folders, which they can view afterwards in my frontend (think: Dropbox, Google Drive, etc).

I understand that Django has a [built-in storage api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/files/storage/), but it seems to me that I cannot use it because it only deals with file uploads (I am also looking to upload directories and subdirectories). This means that I would need to create a custom method to accomplish what I want.

I am having trouble understanding how to deal with the folder structure that I should follow for this.

I was thinking of creating individual folders for each user once they register to the platform. These folders would be named after the users `uuid`. For example:

1. user: **peter123** registers
2. a uuid of `uc3f-g239-h423-tx3y` is assigned
3. a folder named `uc3f-g239-h423-tx3y` is created in a common directory
4. all files and folders that **peter123** uploads are then stored in folder: `uc3f-g239-h423-tx3y`

The same goes for all subsequent users, having their individual folder names represented by their uuid's.

Structure would be something like this:

```
common
|
|_____uc3f-g239-h423-tx3y
|             |____peter123.txt
|             |____peter123-subfolder
|                        |_____peter123-subfile.csv
|
|_____du3y-dgp7-g9rq-23qp
|             |____bob123.txt
|             |____bob123.mp4
|             |____bob123-subfolder
|                        |_____bob123-subfile.mkv
|
```

Is this an effective structure to accomplish what I am trying to achieve? I am aware of the fact that some file systems such as `ext3` have a sub directory limit, but others such as `ext4` don't.

Considering all information described above, my questions would be:

1. Are there any limitations towards storing files in this manner that I would need to be aware of?
2. Is Django capable of managing the file uploads/downloads or should I look towards something else to do this portion of the application?

I am open to all input, as I understand that there might be better ways to go about this (which I am not aware of). I have done quite a bit of searching on this but am struggling to find an appropriate answer.

**Alternatively, could anyone point me towards any good resources in which I might be able to learn about this topic?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can use `django-storages` to push to minio or amazon S3, with the litte customize `def gen_path(self, instance, filename):` you can have quite close to your goal

Comment: This answer was actually very useful. Can I still protect the files behind a user though? And would storing in data objects defeat the whole purpose of storing directories? (since file objects are non hierarchical).

Comment: I think you can control access per user via queryset or serializer. The structure can help if you need other layer of security (via your files manager)